# TOSVersion gives wrong result

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have client 64 bit Windows 7 installed on his computer. Below same codes gives different results on a dummy application and in my application. My application is group project and have 25 packages.

```
TOSVersion.Name: Windows 7
TOSVersion.ToString: Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (Version 6.1, Build 7601, 64-bit Edition)

TOSVersion.Name: Windows XP
TOSVersion.ToString: Windows XP Service Pack 3 (Version 5.1, Build 2600, 64-bit Edition)
```

What may be causing problem?

Manifest file settings Auto Generate. There is not a .manifest file but I could found "supportedOS" entry in .res file in both project. Both of them have same content like below:

```
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
    <application> 
        <!--The ID below indicates app support for Windows Vista -->
        <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
        <!--The ID below indicates app support for Windows 7 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
        <!--The ID below indicates app support for Windows 8 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
        <!--The ID below indicates app support for Windows 8.1 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
        <!--The ID below indicates app support for Windows 10 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>          
    </application> 
</compatibility>
```

Comment: Answer likely to be found in the application manifest. Specifically in the supportedOS entries.

Comment: .. or compatibility settings..

Comment: Thank you both of you. Problem was as Sertaç said :)

Comment: @SertacAkyuz if you write your comment  as answer, I can mark it as correct answer.

Comment: @Enes - done. You're welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Likely cause is that a compatibity fix [(a shim)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/dd837644(v=ws.10)) is applied to the executable on the client's computer; specifically the [WinXPSP3VersionLie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/cc722305%28v%3dws.10%29#compatibility-fixes) fix. 
`TOSVersion` record uses `GetVersionEx` to determine the OS version in its class constructor, which is effected by the shim as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/cc749518%28v%3dws.10%29).

One way to verify is to examine the event log. An event will be logged either it's the user who's applying the fix through program properties dialog ([support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15078/windows-make-older-programs-compatible)) or the [Program Compatibility Assistant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756937.aspx), or through [Application Compatibility Toolkit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562082(v=vs.85).aspx). You can search your executable's name in

```
Event Log\Application and Services\Microsoft\Windows\Application-Experience\Program-Telemetry
```